# trajectory saving problem

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-groovy, hector, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i do bellow tutorial to create hector_slam map with trajectory ,bellow error caused but i can see online map on rviz without any problem and with trajectory, but when i try to save map with hector_geotiff ,map saved without trajectory,
what's problem?

```
[ERROR] [1392637719.233332009]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (1):  

[ERROR] [1392637719.467775930]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
```

slam.launch

```
<launch>

<param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>ros

<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.vcg"/>

<include file="$(find uprobotics)/launch/hector_mapping.launch"/>

<include file="$(find uprobotics)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">
<arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/> 
</include>

</launch>
```

hector_mapping.launch

```
<launch>

<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping"    output="screen">

<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
<!-- Map size / start point -->
<param name="map_resolution" value="0.025"/>
<param name="map_size" value="2048"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="laser_z_min_value" value="-2.5" />
<param name="laser_z_max_value" value="7.5" />

<!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.7" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
</node>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster"      args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 100" />  

</launch>
```

geotiff_mapper.launch

in this file was modified only thing is the path where you save the geotiff generated in this case / home / viki / Desktop / maps

```
<launch>
<arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" default="/base_link"/>
<arg name="trajectory_update_rate" default="4"/>
<arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" default="0.25"/>

<node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
<param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
<param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="$(arg trajectory_source_frame_name)" />
<param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_update_rate)" />
<param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_publish_rate)" />
</node>


<node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
<remap from="map" to="/dynamic_map" />
<param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="/home/viki/Desktop/maps" />
<param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="uprobotics" />
<param name="geotiff_save_period" type="double" value="0" />
<param name="draw_background_checkerboard" type="bool" value="true" />
<param name="draw_free_space_grid" type="bool" value="true" />
</node>

</launch>
```

and is run as follows

$ roscore

$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

$ rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node

$ uprobotics slam.launch

this is output of `rosservice call trajectory`:

```
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
      secs: 1392735924
      nsecs: 220875750
    frame_id: /map
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.0281494148076
      y: -0.153469845653
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.124254979005
      w: 0.992250321337
```

and this is out put of `rostopic echo trajectory`:

```
header: 
        seq: 0
        stamp: 
          secs: 1392735923
          nsecs: 969870750
        frame_id: /map
      pose: 
        position: 
          x: 0.0127319339663
          y: -0.167738348246
          z: 0.0
        orientation: 
          x: 0.0
          y: 0.0
          z: -0.123253038025
          w: 0.992375276102
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130336/trajectory-saving-problem/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So you see the trajectory in rviz? That indicates that the trajectory server indeed runs and generates data correctly. [hector_geotiff](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_geotiff) requests the robot trajectory from [hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server) via a service, so to see if this service provides reasonable data you can execute

```
rosservice call trajectory
```

Does this service call work? What is the output? If you post output, please add to your original question by editing it.

/edit: Ok, it turns out that the trajectory is indeed not visible for the tutorial launch file, as we changed things so plugins are used for adding visualization to hector_geotiff. To get trajectory visualization make sure to set the "plugins" parameter where you launch the hector_geotiff node, for example:

```
  <node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
    <param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps" />
    <param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="" />
    <param name="geotiff_save_period" type="double" value="45" />

    <param name="plugins" type="string" value="hector_geotiff_plugins/TrajectoryMapWriter" />
  </node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-18**:
yes, service call work and i added output of it in original question as you said.
what's problem dear stefan?
can i finally save *.tiff map file with trajectory?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-02-18**:
Well it´s highly unusual that there is only a single pose stored by the trajectory server. Never seen that before. What´s the output of "rostopic echo trajectory"?

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-18**:
No there was plenty of
" header:
seq: 0
stamp:
secs: 1392735924
nsecs: 220875750
frame_id: /map
pose:
position:
x: 0.0281494148076
y: -0.153469845653
z: 0.0
orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: -0.124254979005
w: 0.992250321337 "
but i added one of them,
i include output of "rostopic echo trajectory" in original question,
what do you think Dear Stefan?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-02-19**:
Ok, summing up:

- You see the trajectory in rviz.
- When rostopic echoing and rosservice calling the "trajectory" topic and service, respectively, you see an  array of poses getting printed.
- When looking at generated GeoTiffs you see the map as expected, but no path of the robot.

To me this looks like the service call from hector_geotiff to hector_trajectory_server somehow does not work, but I don´t see a reason for that right now.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-19**:
Thanks Dear Stefan for your time,
can i ask you to publish a launch file for me?,
I have two dynamixel  motor to fix my laser with gyro.
I want to create a savable map with trajectory...
Thanks So much.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-02-20**:
I don´t have time to spare to experiment with a system I have no access to. Things also seem to work for other people, so it looks like something is wrong with your setup. I´d suggest trying from scratch on another machine for example.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-21**:
Thanks Dear Stefan for your time.

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-22**:
Dear Stefan, I think hector_geotiff package is something wrong, because i can see trajectory in rviz and just when i want to save tiff file by hector_geotiff, map saved without trajectory...
what do you think Dear?
Can you change hector_geotiff package to solve this problem?

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-23**:
Dear Stefan, i do tutorial on this link http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData to be sure my launch file is correct, but still i can see trajectory on rviz and i can't save map with trajectory.
as you said i do these work on two pcs and both have same result.
please Help me Stefan?
and i tested on groovy and hydro ...

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-02-23**:
See updated answer. Apologies for the delay, should have tested earlier myself :)

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-02-24**:
Thank you Dear Stefan, my problem solved by your useful help...